# Can't set attribute size="" in liquid-html element

Tags: javascript, html, sass, liquid

I'm passing dinamcally items to a select>option to make a list selectable with items and also I want to show that "list" inline (without the drop down), to do that i did the next things:

This is my liquid code

```
<select class="pattern-select single-option-selector single-option-selector-{{ section.id }} product-form__input" id="SingleOptionSelector-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}" data-index="option{{ forloop.index }}">
  {% for value in option.values %}
      <option value="{{ value | escape }}"{% if option.selected_value == value %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

And this the css that I'm using

```
.pattern-select {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 3em;    
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

.pattern-select option{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    float:left;
}
```

I just need to add `size="3"` as attribute in `<select...` to end with that function, but when I put it manually, the `size="3"` is not processed and it is as if the attribute had not been set and therefore I cannot display the select>option structure inline.

This is what my html output look like:

```
<select class="pattern-select single-option-selector single-option-selector-product-template product-form__input" id="SingleOptionSelector-0" data-index="option1">
   <option value="S" selected="selected">S</option>
   <option value="M">M</option>
   <option value="L">L</option>
   <option value="XL">XL</option>
</select>
```

Any tip?

Cheers!

Comment: have you tried inline css?

Comment: Hi @RodenerDajes, yes, that's how I'm writing `size="3"`

Comment: Can you specify if you use npm package "liquid", version of it. And versions of node and npm?

Comment: Well, finally I've found a rudimentary but functional way to achieve it.. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally because i can't extend this problem anymore, I got the `<select>` id and pass it via javascript the property size perse:

```
document.getElementById("SingleOptionSelector-0").size = "3";
```